# What are UserControls and ContentPresenters and how can I use them to display and change my content?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

Edit: Oh my. I forgot to commit before changing my code and unfortunately the program is not running properly. I will try to describe what displays currently and what I hope to accomplish. What I currently have is a WPF window called SelectScreenShots. When the window loads it takes screen shots of all the active windows associated with the program and renders them as bitmaps, it loads the items control which displays two columns one containing all the images and one containing buttons.

When the user clicks on one of the images, I want that image to display in the same window only enlarged. There is a back button at the top of the window and when the user clicks the back button, I want it to go back to the list displaying all the images.

I am inexperienced with WPF. I have only made very simple GUIs, but I am trying to expand my knowledge. I am trying to build a GUI that displays all the active windows from an application and allows the user to click on an image in the list to display a large image. I was told I need to accomplish this using a `UserControl` and a `ContentPresenter`, but I don't understand how the two relate to each other and how to bind my list of images to the `UserControl`.

Originally I was using an `ItemsControl`. The xaml is below:

```
<ItemsControl Name="_itemsControl">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Name="_imageGrid">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="550"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Name="_image" Grid.Column="0" Height="400" Width="550" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment ="Center" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding ''}" 
                               MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="_addscreenshot" Click="_addscreenshot_Click" Content="Select Screenshot" 
                                    Height="30" Width="150" Margin="3.5,0,3.5,7"/>
                        <Button Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="_removescreenshot" Click="_removescreenshot_Click" Content="Remove Screenshot" 
                                    Height="30" Width="150" Margin="3.5,0,3.5,7"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I am binding a list of bitmaps to _image in my code behind.

I am assuming I need to take this `ItemsControl` and transfer it over the `UserControl` and then display the `UserControl` in a `ContentPresenter` on my main window.

Forgive me if this is completely incorrect. I have tried doing my own research however the explanations are very broad and vague, I assume because UserControls are by nature broad and vague so that they can accomplish a number of tasks.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `ItemsControl`, for one, seems correct. Anytime you need to display "Items" in WPF (whatever these items may be), you use an `ItemsControl`, so your approach is OK so far. What I don't understand is how do you want to relate that to a `UserControl` and why. It would be helpful if you posted a screenshot of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @HighCore Sorry I can't provide a screenshot. I changed my code without committing :| . I'll work on fixing that. I will expand on my above edit. I want users to be able to click on a small image and open up that image, but larger. Originally I was trying to use page navigation to do this, but I was told to use a UserControl and a ContentPresenter to display and switch between content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a `ContentPresenter` is to display the content within a [`ContentControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), an example being the `Button` class. As opposed to creating a new `UserControl` or using a `ContentControl` with a `ContentPresenter`, I'd create a custom control inheriting from the `Control` class. Here is a very basic (i.e. lack of MVVM and `Style`s) solution that I've devised.

The output of the code below is this:

[image]

**ImageDialogue control**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace ImageControl
{
    public class ImageDialogue : Control
    {
        public ImageDialogue()
        {
            //applies the default style for the control (see ControlTemplate below)
            DefaultStyleKey = typeof (ImageDialogue);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof (ImageSource), typeof (ImageDialogue), new PropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource)));

        public ImageSource ImageSource
        {
            get { return (ImageSource) GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

**The default style** (declared within App.xaml just for demonstrative purposes)

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!-- declaring the style and template without a key enables them to be consumed as the default style --> 
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageDialogue}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageDialogue}">
                        <Grid Background="DarkGray"
                              Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                              Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
                            <Image Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="ImageControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ImageControl="clr-namespace:ImageControl"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <Image Source="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-WuasmTMjMA4/TY0SS4TzIMI/AAAAAAAAFB4/6alyfOzWsqM/s640/flowers-wallpapers-love-blooms-roses-bunch-of-flowers.jpg"
                   Margin="5"
                   Stretch="UniformToFill"
                   Height="200"
                   Width="200"
                   MouseUp="Image_MouseUp" />

            <Image Source="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-0JiC3dRE-Vg/UVx_ffJogLI/AAAAAAAAC2w/SxRqMIWfBro/s1600/flowers-pics-flower-colours.jpg"
                   Margin="5"
                   Stretch="UniformToFill"
                   Height="200"
                   Width="200"
                   MouseUp="Image_MouseUp" />

            <Image Source="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-zoLd-fBa48A/UYoQqgrBqWI/AAAAAAAAABY/aQAT7EtZvUc/s1600/flowers-13.jpg"
                   Margin="5"
                   Stretch="UniformToFill"
                   Height="200"
                   Width="200"
                   MouseUp="Image_MouseUp" />
        </ItemsControl>

        <ImageControl:ImageDialogue x:Name="ImageDialogue"
                                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                                    Height="500"
                                    Width="500"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow code-behind**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ImageControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Image_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Image image = sender as Image;

            // the above is an implicit cast, thus the reference will be null if it fails
            if (image == null)
                return;

            ImageDialogue.ImageSource = image.Source;
            ImageDialogue.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
   }
}
```